# Is it possible to pass a std::vector to an MFC function that expects a CArray?

Tags: c++, vector, mfc, interop, dynamic-arrays

I have a

```
std::vector<double> vecArr
```

How can I pass it to the function

```
BOOL AddData (const CArray<double,double>& arrValue)
```

?

---

The comments suggest that this is not possible, and it was suggested that I convert the `std::vector` object to a `CArray` object first. However, that is very expensive in terms of time—I measured a 7 second vs. 7 millisecond difference on my machine.

```
// Copy vector v1 to v2  (very fast)
vector<double> v1;
v1.resize(1000000);         // 1 Mio elements
vector<double> v2(v1);      // ~7ms 

// Copy vector v1 to CArray a1 (very slow)
CArray<double, double> a1;
a1.SetSize(v1.size());      // Reserve 1 Mio elements
vector<double>::iterator it = v1.begin();
while (it != v1.end())     // ~7sec ! :((
   arr.Add(*it++);` `
```

Is there some way to improve the performance of this solution?

Comment: Easy -- You change `AddData`'s parameter to `std::vector<double>` and drop using MFC container classes.

Comment: Or, you could create a `CArray` and copy all of the elements to it and then pass it to the function `AddData`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't understand it exactly. Unfortunately I can't change the AddData() signature

Comment: @EmmanuelMathi-Amorim yes I know this, but the container is big (~100'000 elements). Is it possible without copying?

Comment: @TomTom -- A `CArray` is not a `std::vector`, plain and simple.  Just because both classes do similar things doesn't mean you can interchange them.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie pass a vector to POD someFunc(&v[0],v.size()) is very effective! I thought there is  some similar for CArray.

Comment: @TomTom: `CArray`has a method for doing thinks like you last comment, it is the `GetData()`; however it does not fit what you are asking in your question.

Comment: If you can't change the signature of `AddData`, then maybe you can use `CArray<double,double>` instead of `std::vector<double>` on the caller side. `CArray` and `std::vector` are two different things and you simply cannot interchange them. `CArray` is still quite effective even if it is outdated and not very standard.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thanks for the clarification. But it's very expensive (see my copy code snippet below) I think I have to replace my std::vector to a CArray. :(

Comment: @TomTom that's it. If the array is big, copying is probably not an option. And `CArray` works in a pretty similar fashion to `std::vector`, so the code won't change that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to "reinterpret" a `std::vector` as a `CArray`. Although both classes represent the same concept, they are not the same. It's like two completely different languages. You might say the same thing I am saying in Russian, but I cannot understand it because I cannot read Russian!

You basically have three options:

1. *Convert* the `std::vector` into a `CArray`.

   Much like translating from Russian into English, this takes time. Fortunately, unlike linguistic translation, it is a trivial process. You simply iterate through the original `std::vector` and copy each of the elements into a new `CArray`.

   If you take proper care to pre-allocate space for the required number of elements, this operation can be done in O(n) time and space. It isn't free, but it isn't (generally) prohibitively expensive, either.
2. *Change the function's interface* so that it accepts a `std::vector` object.

   Arguably, this is the *best* option. You should standardize on the standard library container classes and move away from the MFC container classes. There are many reasons for this, including interoperability and performance.

   The obvious downside of this is that it requires changes to the code—potentially massive and breaking changes—which are time-consuming and error-prone. But it is a very beneficial refactoring that really needs to be done anyway, unless the code is completely on life-support and not being further improved. Once the refactoring is done, there will be no performance costs at runtime, producing an ideal solution.
3. *Adopt a "mixed" solution* where you change the function's interface to accept a lowest-common-denominator parameter. Specifically, change the function so that it accepts a C-style array (one parameter that is a pointer to the first element in the array, and a second parameter that denotes the length of the array).

   This results in maximum compatibility, since both a `std::vector` object and a `CArray` object can be treated/reinterpreted as if they are a basic C-style array, and therefore minimizes the number of invasive changes that are necessary throughout the code base. Locally, you can use whichever container type is convenient, then for interoperability, you pass the lowest-common-denominator, which is trivially obtained.

   The disadvantages of this solution are numerous, and are the same as the reasons for using a type-safe container in the first place, so if solution #2 is at all possible, you should prefer to do that.

Comment: after years I found this again and I agree that this is very well explained and considers all situations.